# Write $\cos(1+i)$ in the form $x+iy$, reduced as far as possible.

Tags: complex-analysis

I understand that $\cos(1+i) = \dfrac{e^{(1+i)} + e^{-(1+i)}}{2}$.

But where do I go from here?

Comment: @TheGreatDuck IMO, the attempt shown by OP is enough effort from his/her side.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck Do you want that OP must tell us that how has he written this (I.e. proof of relation if $\cos x$ and complex numbers)? Really?

Comment: @TheGreatDuck Why do we need citation? To verify whether he is right or wrong? I think, that (s)he is asking us, that means (s)he has already assumed that we already know this formula, Even I don't provide citation to every theorem or formula while asking any question, not only me, almost everyone doesn't.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck What must be justified, why should be justified? What's wrong in using this *well-known* formula without citation? Can you exactly tell what should be edited in the question?

Comment: I also think this demand for "rigor" is a bit misplaced. Certainly in the complex domain one should only use facts that are true in that domain, not (for example) claiming that $\sqrt{ab} = \sqrt a\sqrt b.$ But the fact cited in the question is relatively elementary in complex analysis.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck If you still think so, then we agree to disagree.

Comment: If you find any answer useful, please accept the best answer See : [How does accepting an answer work ?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 4):

**hint**

$$e^{1+i}=e.e^{1.i}=e (\cos (1)+i\sin (1)) $$

result
$$\cos (1+i)=$$
$$\cosh (1)\cos(1)+i\sinh(1)\sin(1) $$